# array unintentionally gets converted to object with supertest

Tags: node.js, supertest

the array bellow (query.conditions) gets converted to an object somehow,
any idea why and how I can prevent it ?

The request:

```
          supertest(options.url)
            .get('/api/action')
            .expect(200)
            .query({
              conditions: 
                [
                  { 'user' : user._id },
                  { 'type' : 14 },
                  { 'what' : 4 },
                ]
            })
```

What the server gets:

```
{
  "conditions": {
    "user": "5592cc851f3febd016dae920",
    "type": "14",
    "what": "4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seem to be [issues with query string serialization](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/552) in `superagent` (which is used by `supertest`).

To work around that, you can use [`qs.stringify()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#stringifying) on your data:

```
var qs = require('qs');

...

supertest(options.url)
  .get('/api/action')
  .expect(200)
  .query(qs.stringify({
    conditions: 
      [
        { 'user' : user._id },
        { 'type' : 14 },
        { 'what' : 4 },
      ]
  }))
```

(if at all possible, it might be more appropriate to POST JSON instead, though)